# Custom Drawer navigator in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a custom drawer navigator with screens 1.CreateList,2.SavedList ,In the given image 2 same screen title available,Suppose if i remove a Drawer.screen That screen will not be consider for navigation .How to create a fully custom sidebar?

```
//DrawerNav

 export const DrawerNav = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
   <Drawer.Navigator
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Create List" component={MobileShoppingList} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="SavedList" component={SavedList} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="profileStack" component={profileStack} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>);};

//Custom Drawer 

<DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
  <DrawerItemList {...props} />
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("profileStack")}>
      <Text>
        Create List
      </Text>
      <Image
        resizeMode={"contain"}
        style={{ height: 16 }}
        source={require("./assets/Images/list.png")}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("SavedList")}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "Raleway-Medium" }}>
        Saved List
      </Text>
      <Image
        resizeMode={"contain"}
        style={{ height: 16 }}
        source={require("./assets/Images/list.png")}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove  <DrawerItemList {...props} /> from custom drawer

```
//DrawerNav

 export const DrawerNav = ({ navigation }) => {
 return (
 <Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Create List" component={MobileShoppingList} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="SavedList" component={SavedList} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="profileStack" component={profileStack} />
</Drawer.Navigator>);};

//Custom Drawer 

<DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("profileStack")}>
    <Text>
      Create List
    </Text>
    <Image
      resizeMode={"contain"}
      style={{ height: 16 }}
      source={require("./assets/Images/list.png")}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("SavedList")}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "Raleway-Medium" }}>
      Saved List
    </Text>
    <Image
      resizeMode={"contain"}
      style={{ height: 16 }}
      source={require("./assets/Images/list.png")}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```